# How to authenicate Google Apps script with consumer Key Secret

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a example/Script to authenicate Google Apps script with consumer Key Secret in Google apps

Any related help will be appreciated.

Comment: where do you want to authenticate your script? google, facebook, twitter...

Comment: authenticate in Google

Comment: have you tried a simple search on this forum ? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Doauth